# gmaps.js geocoder not working?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails, gmaps.js

I am trying to building a Rails blog that displays a location on a google map using an address belonging to the object in the database. 
I have been using gmaps.js, with this script in the head:

```
<head> <script src='https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'></script> </head>
```

And the partial that I am rendering looks like this:

```
 <script>
  var map = new GMaps({
  div: '#map',
  lat: -12.043333,
  lng: -77.028333,
  scrollwheel:  false,
  draggable: false,
  clickable: true
});

  GMaps.geocode({
  address: "<%= @post.address %>",
  callback: function(results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
      map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
      map.addMarker({
        lat: latlng.lat(),
        lng: latlng.lng()
      });
    }
  }
});
   </script>
```

Right now the partial displays a map, but it does not display the location that is associated with the @post, even though `<%= @post.address %>` does display the address outside of the map context.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm sure it must be a relatively simple problem, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by: even though <%= @post.address %> does display the address outside of the map context? also could you share a screenshot

Comment: I tested it in the view.html.erb to check that '.address' wasn't nil, and it isn't nil. So I figure the problem is in the gmaps code. I can share a picture if you really want it, but it's just a map on a page at the moment displaying some default coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check that the address could be geocoded with Google's API. You could try out the address using the [GMaps playground here](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geocoding.html). When I used my long address, I discovered that it wasn't geocoding but it found a shorter address pretty quickly.